# Why is upower output different from /sys/class/power_supply contents?

Tags: power-management

I'm debugging a situation where the remaining battery percentage report is not accurate for my newly installed battery.

Regarding [the answer of my previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562588/65781), various tools query the battery information directly from the battery itself. However, output of battery voltage differs between `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/voltage_now` and `upower`:

```
# upower
    voltage:             10.974 V

# /sys/...
10500000
```

Moreover, `upower` updates its statistics every 2 minutes, where `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/voltage_now` seems to be updated live. This also indicates that the sources of those two data-sources are probably different.

So, what are the data sources of those two data sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, output of battery voltage differs between `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/voltage_now` and `upower`

**This your question.**

> Moreover, upower updates its statistics every 2 minutes

**Here you answered it yourself**.
It's just the update time. If you `cat voltage_now` and run `upower` at its update time, you will get the same result.

```bsh
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1 |egrep 'updated|voltage'; cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/voltage_now
  updated:              Mon 17 Feb 2020 07:07:31 AM CAT (0 seconds ago)
    voltage:             17.156 V
17156000
```

Notice when the **updated** time is **0 seconds ago**, the value is the same. Try the command multiple times and you see a larger difference when the time is **120 seonds ago**.

If you want `upower` to give you an updated value instantly, you can force a refresh with

```bsh
dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1  org.freedesktop.UPower.Device.Refresh; upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1 |egrep 'updated|voltage'
```

> So, what are the data sources of those two data sources?

The data source for `upower` is `upowerd`. `upowerd` would read the data from `/sys/.../BAT1/*` and store the history in `/var/lib/upower/`. When `upower` sends a request before the poll time configured for `Upower`, `upowerd` would reply with `limiting data to last 120 seconds` and returns the historical value.

Comment: So you mean reading the `.../voltage_now` file actually creates a telegram, asks battery voltage from the battery pack via SMBUS and returns the answer (but not cache it for `upower` or like) under the hood?

Comment: @ceremcem: reading voltage_now directly would always give the realtime value, but upower doesn't read it directly, it read the value in `upowerd`. I added more info to the answer to explain this. Hope it's clear now

Comment: The answer of my previous question (see the link in my question) states that the voltage is queried via SMBUS. I'm still wondering if that SMBUS communication takes place as soon as we attempted to read the `voltage_now` file. That is still a mystery.

Comment: I guess, reading the `voltage_now` file via `cat` (or anything that reads the file) triggers a function in the kernel, kernel connects to the battery pack via SMBUS, read the data and write it to `voltage_now` file and let us read the file. It would be pointless otherwise. How could I read the `voltage_now` file in every second and get the "correct" voltage value then?

Comment: You are certainly right! When you `cat voltage_now`, the kernel would run some *magic* code and connect to the battery via SMBus, read the data and make it available via `voltage_now`.